# If a URL endpoint has a period(.) then not able to access the vuejs route

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuex

Vue.js

```
{ path: '/authenticate/:id', component: authenticate },
```

**URL- http://localhost:8080/authenticate/test.qwerty**

Error - Cannot GET /authenticate/test.querty

**If URL - http://localhost:8080/authenticate/test**

It works fine.

If the endpoint has a period(.) then not able to access the route. How to resolve this issue?

Comment: vuejs router uses regexp, just add \ before dot

Comment: You can check this issue perhaps it could help. https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/576

Comment: `Cannot GET` – this is a server error, no? Are you sure your server is configured correctly?